# How does one program for first time and reprogram microcontrollers that are mounted to a PCB?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, programming, prototyping

Arduino Unos and Microchip Curiosity Nanos are for prototyping and easy and ready to program, but now I am struggling to find the resource material that would detail taking the chip off the breakout board and putting it onto a PCB board to save room on the PCB.

For say, the Curiosity Nano, I'm not entirely sure what I can cut off of the ATmega4809 and still be able to program it. Looking around I think I just need terminal pins/leads exposed on the MOSI, MISO, and SCK pins of the microcontroller and the USBASP(?) leads that attach correspondingly to my PC and then I should be able to flash hex files by selecting the correct COM port.

Does anyone have good info for this?

edit: Do i need to install a bootloader using a UPDI like in this webpage? technoblogy.com/show?2QVZ

Comment: Have you consulted the datasheets for the uCs you're interested in? It includes things like sample circuits for in-system programming,

Comment: Easiest way is to look for reference designs including programming interface and customize them to your needs.

Comment: Microchip will sell you a preprogrammed IC for not very much extra  money, they also don't really care about volumes and have no minimum order . https://get.microchipdirect.com/microchip-programming-services

Comment: Do i need to install a bootloader using a UPDI like in this webpage?      http://www.technoblogy.com/show?2QVZ

Comment: In case you hadn't considered this alternative, if you are using through hole packaged uC's, you can program them off the target board and insert them into a DIP socket on the target board.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a general answer since that seems to be what you're looking for.

Dev boards usually include a built in programmer, or a boot-loader so that they can be programmed without any additional hardware (to make them more accessible).

Most MCUs need only power, bypass caps, and maybe a pullup or cap on a reset line to function on their own. Check the datasheet for an "typical application circuit".

To program the bare MCU you will usually use a separate programmer. Almost every manufacturer has "hobby grade" programmer that is cheap and will work just fine. For example the pickit-4 or stmlink v2.

These connect to certain programming pins on the MCU. You connect it up according to the datahsheet, hit *program* in your ide and that's basically it.

On your custom board you would put the programming pins on a header. For example on a PIC the programming pins are:

1. MCLR (VPP)
2. PWR (VDD)
3. GND
4. DATA (PGD)
5. CLOCK (PGC)

*Side notes:*

You will have to do some installation steps to get the programmer recognized by your ide. If everything is from the same company (like microchip) things are more likely to auto-detect and "just work".

One advantage of using a seperate programmer is that many dev boards use a bootloader that takes up space on the MCU. No bootloader means more space for your application.

If you are using a discrete programmer, you do not need a bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

In production conditions, either..

- the chips are ordered from the factory or an authorized distributor that can program them.
- Test pads are designed into the PCB and a programmer with pogo-pins is pushed onto the board to make connection and the chip is programmed.

Comment: If there is room, always add connectors to the board. You can exclude them from the BoM in production, if you wish to use stuff like pogo pins or card edge to shave down connector costs. To bother with such, you'll need quite high production volumes though. For something with <100 boards per year I'd just use a mounted connector.

Answer (score 0):

ATmega4809 (and other new Mega 0-series) doesn't uses old SPI (MISO, MOSI, etc) programming interface. It uses UPDI interface for ISP. USBAsp aren't designed to work with that interface. You will need UPDI programmer for that (official ones are Snap! & Pickit 4).

You can also burn some sort of bootloader while it's in dev board (which has a built-in UPDI programmer) with serial programming. But care must be taken and that is out of scope of this question to discuss the whole process & caveats.

Opposed to this, Atmega8 on the Arduino Uno are "classic" AVR part which uses SPI interface for ISP. You can expose this, also don't forget to include RESET and power. There are standard 6 & 10 pin headers for AVR SPI ISP:

[image]